# I am having trouble with some basic JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

The return from an external application is an Input Stream that looks like this:

```
JSONObj = {    
           "output":
             [
               {
                 "box":[0, 44, 43, 189],
                 "text":"~9 000 -"
               }
             ]
          }
```

I'm having trouble parsing the JSON in Java

The 'JSONOBJ' keeps coming back as an Invalid Token.

Is there a way to simply begin parsing at the '['?

Comment: Did you tried to use string manipulation to get rid on `JSONObj =` part? Or maybe strip out the first line entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice against manipulating the JSON prior to parsing it. If you want to cut out parts it's a sign that your target data structure (the Java class you're intending to get) does not match the data you're receiving. These two should be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this into any decent JSON parser will tell you that this is invalid JSON.

Particularily, at line 6, you should remove the manual line breaks, since JSON only permits explicit ones using the line seperator `\n`:

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "box": [
        0,
        44,
        43,
        189
      ],
      "text": "~9 000 -"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be:

```
json = json.substring(json.indexOf('{'))
```

And I actually disagree with Nicktar's statement, since that external program isn't even returning valid JSON (and I'd consider it a very very stupid implementation to be frank). There is no need in saying "hey, that's an object" because that's actually implicit. If a JSON starts with `{`, it's an object, if it starts with `[`, it's an array.